# Creating Dynamic RadioButtons from JSON Data

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, jsonparser

I have fetched data from an api and I want to display the small array as a radio button as user should have only one selection.

Here's my code to get data from network:

```
if (coachName != null && coachId != null) {
        nameTV.setText(coachName);
        fetchBatches(coachId);
        createGroups();
    }
```

in `fetchBatches(id)`, I have done this in json response method:

```
if (response != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Batches Response:\t" + response.toString());
                        try {
                            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.toString());

                            String message = object.getString("message");

                            JSONArray array = object.getJSONArray("batch_details");
                            for (int m = 0; m < array.length(); m++) {

                                JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(m);

                                name_batch = jsonObject.getString("batch_name");
                                id_batch = jsonObject.getString("batch_id");

                                batch = new BatchResponse();
                                batch.setBatchId(id_batch);
                                batch.setBatchName(name_batch);

                                list.add(batch);

                            }
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

It works well and the method to create the radiobuttons:

```
radioButtons = new RadioButton[list.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        radioButtons[i] = new RadioButton(this);
        radioButtons[i].setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        batchGroup.addView(radioButtons[i]);
        radioButtons[i].setText(list.get(i).getBatchName());
        radioButtons[i].setChecked(false);
    }
```

but nothing shows on the screen. Here are the global variables used for each method:

```
private RadioGroup batchGroup;
private BatchResponse batch;
private List<BatchResponse> list = new ArrayList<>();
private String name_batch, id_batch;
private RadioButton[] radioButtons;
```

Am I setting it up wrong? I need help with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call  createGroups() method after for loop in fetchBatches(coachId) method.